# Variadic template specialization with const reference

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-specialization, const-reference

How to specialize variadic template function that has const reference for an argument?

Example:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T foo(Args... args) = delete;

template<> int foo(int a, const char* str, const Test& t) { .... } // Fails to compile
//template<> int foo(int a, const char* str, Test ) { .... } // Ok

int main() {

    auto i = foo<int>(10, "test string!", t);
    return 0;
}
```

When invoking function foo with declared `const Test&`argument, the compiler fails to see specialized function and fallbacks to deleted function:

```
 error: use of deleted function ‘T foo(Args ...) [with T = int; Args = {int, const char*, Test}]’
     auto i = foo<int>(10, "test string!", t);
```

The above code compiles fine if I remove const reference from argument. What am I doing wrong?

The code can be found [here](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/MMSCQJVOGR)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Automatic template deduction is not smart enough to guess that you want it to set the last template parameter to `const Test&` instead of `Test`. More exactly type deduction always remove cv qualifiers from a type.

You new explicit template instantiation here:

```
auto i = foo<int, int, const char *, const Test&>(10, "test string!", t);
```

Comment: Of course, I totally forgot about explicit instantiation. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 7):

This is because the template arguments which the primary template deduce for your call are `int`, `const char*`, and `Test`, not `const Test&`. This means that your specialization is not used because the template arguments don't match the parameters.

Your simplest option is to provide a separate overload rather than a specialization:

```
template <typename T>
T foo(int a, const char* str, const Test& t) { /*...*/; }
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb609e21664d14b6)